# Error lens kubernetes when try to connect

Tags: kubernetes

Try to add new cluster and connect it , but error shown :

What is this error means ?

What can i provide to solve my problem ?

```
Error: error loading config file "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Lens\kubeconfigs\b5037fca-b872-417d-aedc-80caab820992": 

v1.Config.AuthInfos: []v1.NamedAuthInfo: v1.NamedAuthInfo.AuthInfo: 
v1.AuthInfo.ClientCertificateData: decode base64: illegal base64 data at input byte 604, error found in #10 byte of ...|ldkYWs2eE"}}]}|..., 
bigger context ...|jZNWm5yU3NNVVBSbjFrd0NheFJyNE5pN04zNlN5dldkYWs2eE"}}]}|...

proxy exited with code: 1
```

Comment: Please provide more [details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Which kind of cluster do you use? Is that Minikube on Windows or Kubernetes on Docker Desktop? Which version of Kubernetes do you use? What have you tried? How do you try connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

I would just make a backup of the mentioned directory and then delete it and try to add it once again. Seems to be a config that is copied from kubernetes cli that is somehow not readable.